# The privilege icon is missing

Tags: bug, design, android-app, privileges

On the Android app, when I got the new privilege to edit questions and answers instantly, the privilege icon is missing in the "Achievements" tab in the topbar:

[image]

The is supposed to be a picture there, which is an up and down arrow picture like this screenshot on my computer:

[image]

So can we add the privilege icon back into the "Achievements" tab in the topbar please?